# I can't access variable from base class c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int x;
}
public class MyClass2: MyClass
{
    x = 1;    
}
```

I'm trying to access variable x from base class but I get an error saying that the name x does not exists in current context.

Comment: Are you actually trying to set that Field in the middle of *nowhere*?

Comment: you can't  assignt x=1 there. You need to assign it inside of a method or a constructor.

Answer (score 6):

You can access it from inside a method like this:

```
public class MyClass2: MyClass
{
    private void MyMethod()
    {
         x = 1;
    }  
}
```

Or from a different class:

```
var test = new MyClass2();
test.x = 1;
```

If you intend for your `x` field to be public, you should consider changing it to a property and capitalizing it, like this:

```
public int X { get; set; }
```

You can read about the difference between fields and properties [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property). If you do make it a property, be sure to follow Microsoft design guidelines and use PascalCase. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-properties).

Answer (score -1):

Try to make your variables public and if this doesn't work try to initialize your variable inside the MyClass and not in the MyClass2

Also happy new year

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: `public MyClass2() { x = 1; }`

Comment: x is already public. The problem comes from what @marsh-wiggle wrote.